# Server Sent Events using NodeJS and Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I receive updates (messages) from a **Redis** Database and I need to show those messages in real time on the client, for this purpose I'm using **SSE** (Server Sent Events).

So, my code looks like this:

Client side javascript:

```
var source = new EventSource('/updates');

source.addEventListener('pmessage', function(e) {
  console.log('Event: ' + e.event);
  console.log('Data: ' + e.data);
}, false);
```

Server side (Node + Express):

```
    req.socket.setTimeout(Infinity);

    var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
    var client = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {ignore_subscribe_messages: true});
    client.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);

    client.psubscribe('updates');

    client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  });

  client.on('psubscribe', function (pattern, count) {
    console.log('psubscribe pattern: ' + pattern);
    console.log('psubscribe count: ' + count);
  });

  client.on('pmessage', function (pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log('pmessage pattern: ' + pattern);
    console.log('pmessage from channel: ' + channel);
    console.log('pmessage message: ' + message);
    res.write("data: " + message + '\n\n');
  });

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });
  res.write('\n');
```

I do not receive any updates from the server to the client (the server receive the message correctly from redis).

If I refresh the server I receive this error: **net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**

I'm new to SSE, so probably I'm doing it wrong. I hope in your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write `res.flush()` every time you need to send messages to the client, in my case:

```
  client.on('pmessage', function (pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log('pmessage pattern: ' + pattern);
    console.log('pmessage from channel: ' + channel);
    console.log('pmessage message: ' + message);
    res.write("data: " + message + '\n\n');
    res.flush();
  });
```

Solved.

Comment: Wow it works! I have a small question: what does `res.flush()` do? When I run the client and server on `localhost` my SSE works, but when I run them on different domains (e.g., client on `localhost` sends request to remote API server) this error happens. `res.flush()` doesn't seem to be in `express`'s API.